# Как сделать цикл с интервалом от π/15 до π с каким-то шагом?

Tags: kotlin, for, range

Мне нужно получить значения X из отрезка [π/15; π], меняющихся с шагом π/15. X будет использоваться в формуле, которую я уже сделал.

Никак не могу составить цикл для получения X, чтобы был определенный шаг π/15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто сделайте цикл от 1 до 15 и умножайте переменную цикла на π/15:

```kotlin
for (i in 1..15) {
    val x = i * Math.PI / 15
    ...
}
```

Comment: Реально ведь можно просто умножать. Спасибо большое!